# Android Google Sheets API update() specific worksheet

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets API (v4) for Android, and I can't find how to use the `values().update()` or `batchUpdate()` methods to update **a specific workbook** of the sheet.

Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: To clarify, I am using THIS API: (from build.gradle)

```
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev28-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Turns out I have to specify the sheet in the ValueRange:

```
   "range": "Sheet2!A1"
```

Hopefully that example can help anyone else who had this problem.

Comment: This shows how to update based on a name, but what if all I have is the worksheet ID?

Answer (score 2):

Be noted that the [v4 version](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration) is JSON-based and often require you to specify a [spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id) of the spreadsheet you are working with. They also often require the ID of the sheet being manipulated. These values appear either as part of the API endpoint URL, as query parameters, or as part of a request body.

[*values().update()*](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

You must specify the spreadsheet ID, range, and a [`valueInputOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption). Your request should be `PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}`.

[*batchUpdate()*](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

You must specify the spreadsheet ID, a [`valueInputOption`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption), and one or more [`ValueRanges`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange). You request should be `POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchUpdate`.

Here are some related theads which might help:

- [Write data to Google Sheet using Google Sheet API V4 - Java Sample Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107237/write-data-to-google-sheet-using-google-sheet-api-v4-java-sample-code)
- [Google Sheets API v4 - How to insert row after the last row with value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615441/google-sheets-api-v4-how-to-insert-row-after-the-last-row-with-value)

Comment: But how do I specify the workbook for a given spreadsheet? Neither the valueInputOption nor the ValueRange seems to have a way to do this.