# Insert data into sheets at last column

Tags: java, android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am integrating Google Sheets with my Android application.
Here is what I need to do,
Each and every day I need to put entry to the last column in my spreadsheet.
I know there is a simple way in Google Apps Script and my script is:

```
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.getRange(0, sheet.getLastColumn() + 1).setValue(myData);
```

I need to know if there is a similar way to do this in android(java) other than connecting my android application and this script via HttpURLConnection.

Thanks.

Comment: There are [Android Add-ons for Google Docs and Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/mobile/); not sure if that is what you are looking for

Comment: Hey thanks! I don't know there is an API to connect with Apps script and mobile apps. But I need to know whether there is a straight way to get my solution.

Comment: AFAIK, Google Sheets API and Apps Script works differently from each other. As stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687676/5995040), they have different style. As a workaround you have to provide the last column/row then count the offset from your requested column/row to get the last column. Hope this helps.