# Append a list in Google Sheet from Python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have a list in Python which I simply want to write (append) in the first column row-by-row in a Google Sheet. I'm done with all the initial authentication part, and here's the code:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```

I do not have any clue as to how I could possibly do this in an easy way.

Comment: there is a method mentioned in the spreadsheets API called spreadsheet.values.append.. have you tried it? If so, what were the errors?  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

Comment: Yes, I did. But I'm not sure how I can use it to append a list to my Google Sheet.

Comment: ok, without knowing what your data looks like or what errors you are getting it's a little hard to help. Could you give more information?

Comment: I haven't got any errors as I'm clueless and haven't tried anything yet. Also, I've already mentioned that the data is a simple list in Python.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about this sample script? This sample appends `list` to column A. The list as data is 2 dimensional array. Please be careful for this. In order to use this script, please enable Sheet API v4 at API console.

#### Sample script :

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

list = [["valuea1"], ["valuea2"], ["valuea3"]]
resource = {
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": list
}
spreadsheetId = "### spreadsheet ID"
range = "Sheet1!A:A";
service.spreadsheets().values().append(
  spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
  range=range,
  body=resource,
  valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED"
).execute()
```

You can see the detail information of spreadsheets.values.append at [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append).

If this sample was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for. it works for me. PS: I had searched a lot on Google Sheets API documentation, but just couldn't figure  out as to how I could input a list.

Comment: @Akshay Maldhure Yes. I also feel that looking for the request parameters for each API is a bit difficult. But now, I'm happy this was helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks again! Do you also know how can the solution you mentioned be modified to update a dictionary instead of a list?

Comment: @Akshay Maldhure In the case of dictionary, the dictionary has to be converted to 2 dimensional array for using ``spreadsheets.values.append``. After the conversion of dictionary, you can append the data. If this is not answer you want, can you submit the situation you want to do as a new question?

Comment: Thanks, for my dictionary `my_dict`, simply passing `my_dict.items()` instead of `list` did the trick.

Comment: @Akshay Maldhure Welcome. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [Google's official quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) + [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46274429/3191896)'s answer, I suggest the following example on how to append rows to a Sheet document:

---

**Take the spreadsheet id from the URL:**

> [image: take the spreadsheet id from the url]

**Script:**

```py
import os
import pickle
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SHEETS_READ_WRITE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
SCOPES = [SHEETS_READ_WRITE_SCOPE]


def main():
    spreadsheet_id = '1TfWKWaWypbq7wc4gbe2eavRBjzuOcpAD028CH4esgKw'  # this is part of the url of google
    rows = [
        ["Hello World", "שלום עולם ינעל העולם", ":)"],
        ["Hello"],
        ["World"]
    ]

    # -----------

    credentials = get_or_create_credentials(scopes=SCOPES)  # or use GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
    service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        range="Sheet1!A:Z",
        body={
            "majorDimension": "ROWS",
            "values": rows
        },
        valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED"
    ).execute()


# Source: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python
def get_or_create_credentials(scopes):
    credentials = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            credentials = pickle.load(token)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', scopes)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials, token)
    return credentials


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- Remember to change - `spreadsheet_id = "<your spreadsheet document id>"`

---

**Result:** 
This is how it looks like if you'll run the script multiple consecutive times

> [image]

Do follow [Google's official quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) and grant yourself API permissions + install these packages:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your cell_values to pandas dataframe and then export it to Google Sheets using gspread_dataframe.set_with_dataframe. It shouldn't cause any quota issues as it sends a full dataframe at once.

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials as GC
df = # YOUR DATAFRAME
document_id = # YOUR DOCUMENT ID
worksheet_name = # YOUR WORKSHEET NAME
gc = gspread.authorize(GC.get_application_default())
doc = gc.open_by_key(document_id)
# Update existing spreadsheet or create a new one
try: 
  sheet = doc.worksheet(worksheet_name)
except:
  sheet = doc.add_worksheet(worksheet_name, rows=1, cols=1)
set_with_dataframe(sheet, df, resize=True)
```

For more information about Python to Google Sheets, you can check out this [article](https://blog.coupler.io/python-to-google-sheets/).

Answer (score 1):

***This code appends a list of lists to each column in google sheets. The my_list as data is a 2-dimensional array.***

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


class spreadSheetLogger:
    def __init__(self, sheetName):
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        credentials = config_file.get_google_credentials()
        # The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
        SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '################'
        SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = '{}!A:A'.format(sheetName, "DefaultName")
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=self.creds)
        sheet = self.service.spreadsheets()

    def spreadLogger(self, message, requestJson, timestamp)
        my_list = [[message], [str(timestamp)], [str(requestJson)]]
        body = {
            "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
            "values": my_list
        }

        request = self.service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=self.SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range=self.SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME,valueInputOption='RAW', body=body)
        response = request.execute()
        return "Record Inserted Successfully"
```

**Output :(in GoogleSheets)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
spreadsheet_id = "give the spreadsheet ID of the sheet you want to append to"
range_name = "specify the range you are looking at eg: A1:B1"

values = [
   [list of cell values per row]
   [additional rows of data]
]

body = {
'values': values
}

result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
    valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
```

from the [docs:](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)

> Updates require a valid ValueInputOption parameter (for singular
>   updates, this is a required query parameter; for batch updates, this
>   parameter is required in the request body). The ValueInputOption
>   controls whether input strings are parsed or not, as described in the
>   following table:
>
> RAW   The input is not parsed and is simply inserted as a string, so the
>
> > input "=1+2" places the string "=1+2" in the cell, not a formula.
> >     (Non-string values like booleans or numbers are always handled as
> >     RAW.)
>
> USER_ENTERED  The input is parsed exactly as if it were entered
>
> > into the Google Sheets UI, so "Mar 1 2016" becomes a date, and "=1+2"
> >     becomes a formula. Formats may also be inferred, so "$100.15" becomes
> >     a number with currency formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas + gspread to export your list as single-column dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials as GC
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
df_my_list = pd.DataFrame(data=my_list[1:], columns=[my_list[0]])
gc = gspread.authorize(GC.get_application_default())
doc = gc.open_by_key(document_id)
document_id = # YOUR DOCUMENT ID
worksheet_name = 'my_list'
# Try to update current worksheet, or create a new one
try: 
  sheet = doc.worksheet(worksheet_name)
except:
  sheet = doc.add_worksheet(worksheet_name, rows=1, cols=1)
set_with_dataframe(sheet, df_my_list, resize=True)
```

For more information about Python to Google Sheets, you can check out this [article](https://blog.coupler.io/python-to-google-sheets/).